# What is the best way integrate custom html with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have got custom `HTML` for `Home Page`,`Category page`,`Product Page`,`Cart Page`,`Checkout Page` and Other needed pages for `Magento 2`. I want know what is the best practice for adding using custom html with `Magento 2`

Comment: @Amam Alam If you are really a certified magento developer with 3+ years experience, please before expone your practice, then community could reply with their.

Comment: @LucaS I am in learning phase of M2, I have already seen M2 theme development documents. I posted this question to know developer view and get step-wise idea for implementation of custom html. If you know kindly post your answer.

Comment: @Amam Alam What do you mean by "custom html"?

Comment: Custom HTML like designer provided page HTML only and i need to integrate that with M2.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your request. You wanna know how to create a page html with magento 2?